# Image does not responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**Out put**

Original Image size : 463px X 339px

I have removed the image due to copy right issues.

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="item-block event-details" id="video-container">
     <img src="/Resources/images/6b0c5d49-9a76-4a09-afb7-5bfa2ed508f7.jpg" class="img-responsive">
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.item-block.event-details {
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
height: 214px;
}

.item-block {
color: #4b4e4e;
border-radius: 4px;
border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #b0b6b6;
position: relative;
margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.img-responsive {
display: block;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
```

**Question :** 
Can you tell me why this is happening ? I need to show the whole image on above parent div sizes.But it's not happening.Can you tell me why ?
In other words,image does not fit into the parent div.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @peirix Sorry.I updated it.

Comment: I still don't see a question.

Comment: Does image not fit into the div ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your parent div needs to be that height for some reason, you could set both `max-width` and `max-height` to `100%`

```
.img-responsive {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto; /* to center the image horizontally in parent div */
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.It's working.Can you tell me why height:auto is not working ?

Comment: @Sampath That's because `height:auto` does not use parent to calculate height, it uses itself. So when you tell it to be as wide as the parent, and figure out the height itself (auto), it will proportionally scale the image accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do the opposite in your .img-responsive css class. Let's try that :

```
.img-responsive {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
max-height: auto;
}
```

Comment: max-height: auto; says invalid property ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't need to write

> max-width:100%;
>   If you want image responsive you can write

```
.img-responsive {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
}
```

if you are using bootstrap then forget about all. you just add the class .img-responsive to img tag.
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/46jyt4d7/1/)